# JOptionPane equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-input, joptionpane

In Java there's a useful class in the standard Swing libraries called 'JOptionPane' that provides a bunch of pre-made but customizable windows for displaying messages and getting (simple) user input.

I know there's 'MessageBox.Show(..)' to display Yes/No/Cancel type messages to the user in C#, but is there an equivalent class (or simple library) that provides easy-to-use customizable input boxes?

Something like the [functionality available](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#input) from [JOptionPane](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Except from vb legacy input-box, there is non. Try implementing by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

As of windows vista, there is the [taskdialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms650925.aspx) api.

This is an os feature, not a c# library, in that sense not what you asked. But it roughly covers the same ground: a more versatile messagebox api, that relieves you from manually layouting simple dialogs. If you google, you can find c# wrappers that emulate this api on older windows.

Finally, here is [a blog entry how to use it in c#](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/09/26/4470.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only thing I can think of that's similar is [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.inputbox.aspx) It's part of Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll so you'll have to add a reference. I don't think there's any way of customizing it more than that, but that does give you a *little* more flexibility.